# Linear regression with AR(1) and Dummy

Tags: r, regression, time-series, autocorrelation, model

I'd like to do an regression with an AR(1) process and a Weekend Dummy.
How can I do this with RStudio?

I found out the general formula as $Y_t=a_0+a_1*Y_{t-1} + \text{Dummy}_t + \epsilon_t$

But I really don't know how to fit the model.
I tried `mod2 <- arima(y1, order =c(1,0,0),include.mean = TRUE)` but there is no use of the Dummy.
`y1` is the data.